# Carmichael number $p \times ... \times q$ , such there are at most $20$ primes in the range $[p,q]$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

Let $N$ be a Carmichael number , $p$ its smallest prime factor, $q$ its largest prime factor.

Which is the largest possible prime $p$, if the range $[p,q]$ only contains
at most $20$ primes ?

The Carmichael number $43\times67\times89\times103\times127\times137$
has this property because there are $20$ primes in the range $[43,137]$.
I did not find an example with $p>43$.

> Can it be shown, that $p>43$ is impossible ?